# This query only returns one results , supposed to return two

Tags: mysql, sql

This query is supposed to return two order_ids .. but only returning one , and the order_ids meet the conditions of the query ... what could be wrong ?

```
SELECT r.*
FROM products_to_products_extra_fields AS p
INNER JOIN orders_roster AS r ON p.products_id = r.products_id
INNER JOIN orders AS o on r.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE p.products_extra_fields_id = 14 AND
     p.products_extra_fields_value between '2013-11-01' and '2013-11-30 23:59:59' AND
     r.roster_status != 'Removed' AND
     o.payment_method = 'Institutional Billing' AND
     o.orders_status < 100001
GROUP BY o.orders_id
ORDER BY DECODE(o.cc_type, 'oFsAfHr7') ASC
```

Comment: Please show the original tables and data that feed that query.

Comment: there could be a multitude of reasons why.  If you can't post the data we really can't help you.  However, whenever I run into an odd query result I usually comment out the where clause and start adding clauses back into it.  Usually this way I can see what line is causing the row to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW r.* ...
```

Also, experiment with the `GROUP BY` clause, which may be causing the rows to collapse on `orders_id`.